# Twig: length giving 1 on empty array?

Tags: templating, craft3, elementquery

This code worked fine in Craft 2:

```
 {% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(category).orderBy('startDate asc').limit(3) %}
 {% set extraEntries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(category).orderBy('startDate asc').offset(3) %}
 {% if extraEntries | length %}
    //do some stuff
 {% endif %}
```

In Craft 3, `{{ extraEntries | length }}` is giving a value a 1 even when there are no entries. For example, `{% for e in extraEntries %}>>>{{e}}{%endfor%}` doesn't output anything. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `extraEntries` is not an array of elements but an object of type `EntryQuery` in order to fetch the entries you have to do

```
{% set extraEntries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(category).orderBy('startDate asc').offset(3).all() %}
```

It was actually the same in Craft 2 but the class had an `iterable` and `countable` interface, so when you do `|length` it actually does `.total()` (to execute the command and fetch the number of rows) These automatic mechanisms are removed/deprecated now thus you have to know what kind of object you use

When you take a look at your cp you'll see a bunch of deprecated warnings.

I suggest you to read the [docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/element-queries.md)